# deploy a react app from GitHub directory to netlify

Tags: reactjs, deployment, web-deployment, netlify, webdeploy

I have a repository on GitHub which has two directories. One directory which is named 'client' contains the client side code (written in reactJs) and the other named 'server' contains a json-server code for my backend. I have already hosted the 'server' directory on heroku. I now want to host the 'client' directory on netlify, but I don't know how to go about it. Please anyone here who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The  Netlify's Build Settings (see docs [here](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started)) have a `Base directory` field where you can let Netlify know to go into the client directory (where it can find a package.json), and then run your react-building commands from there.